# Segmentation error when convert string to array of strings in c

Tags: c

I want to convert a string to an array of strings and I get an error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int count = 0;
    char *str = argv[1]; 
    char *token, *last;
    char **arr_str = calloc(9999, sizeof(char*));
    token = strtok_r(str, " ,", &last);
    arr_str[count] = strcpy(calloc(strlen(token), sizeof(char)), token);
    while (token != NULL) {
        count++;
        token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &last);
        arr_str[count] = strcpy(calloc(strlen(token), sizeof(char)), token);
        printf("%s", arr_str[count - 1]);
    } 
    printf("------------");
    while(arr_str[count])
    printf("%s", arr_str[count--]);
    exit (0);
}
```

how to allocate memory for a string and make a pointer to it from an array?

Comment: What error do you get? You might need to read "[ask]"... An issue that springs right into the eye is that you allocate 1 character too less for the strings, because you need room for the end-of-string marker `'\0'`. And your loop seems a bit complicated.

Comment: 1) Allocate one more byte for each string as the other comment suggests. 2) Think about the case where `strtok_r(NULL, " ", &last);` returns `NULL`. The `strlen(token)` call in the subsequent line would be effectively `strlen(NULL)`, which causes an error.

Comment: What arguments do you provide to your program? You do not check `argc`. How do you know whether `argv[1]` exists?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* always check argument count */
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Not enough arguments given\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0;

    
    char *str = malloc(strlen(argv[1] + 5)); 
    memcpy(str, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    char *token, *last;
    char **arr_str = calloc(9999, sizeof(char*));
    token = strtok_r(str, " ,", &last);
    while ((token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &last)) != NULL) {
        count++;
        /* sizeof(char) is always 1 and is redundant unless you are on
            a obscure platform that it returns other than 1
            which shouldnt exist in modern world
        */
        arr_str[count] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(arr_str[count], token);
    } 
    printf("------------");
    while(arr_str[count])
    printf("%s", arr_str[count--]);
    exit (0);
}
```

`strtok` is destructive meaning it edits strings it encounters, it tried to edit argv which resulted in a segmentation error.
I also edited code to follow better practices and edited formatting.

You need memory for elements of the `arr_str`.

`calloc(9999)` while not great if this not going to end up in a serious application it's not a issue.

`sizeof(char)` should always return 1 on a normal modern system unless you are on extremely obscure system

Use `puts(char* s`) if you don't need string formatting.

You should do input validation.